# Virtual Host keeps pointing to html

Tags: linux, apache, server, debian

I am trying to set up my server, but it keeps poiting to the .html file by default. I have a debian 9 machine with apache. I followed some tutorials about how to create a virtual host. I created an example.conf host in etc/apache2/sites-available. I practically made a copy/paste of the 000.default.conf file. I changed the DocumentRoot to the one I want (/var/www/test/back/) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin machine@mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/test/back
ServerName subdomain.mysite.com
ServerAlias subdomain.mysite.com
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

 <Directory /var/www/test/back>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I disabled the 000.default.conf one and enabled the example.conf one. Then I restarted apache, but when I go to subdomain.mysite.com I don't see my file in /var/www/test/back, I just keep seeing the one in /var/www/html. The only .conf in sites-enabled is example.conf. I am not a server expert, so if you have some idea of where the issue could come from I'd appreciate it!!!

Oh, and when I type "sudo apachectl -S" this is what I get:

`VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex fcgid-pipe: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex fcgid-proctbl: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33`

Comment: Maybe you are simply looking at client side cached responses? Try using a fresh anonymous browser window.

Comment: I tried it from different browsers. But as you can see, in Main DocumentRoot, it points to "/var/www/html". I do not know how to change it, I thought that enabling the example.conf with the desired path (/var/www/test/back/) would be enough.

Comment: It is. The change should get recognized the moment you restart the http server. Try placing a definite syntax error in that configuration. If the http server _still_ starts without an issue then your configutation file does not get regonized. Maybe because you have different installations?

Comment: If I understand correctly your issue, you are currently configuring a Virtual Host with a "Host" value that is still the example "subdomain.mysite.com" domain name.
If you want the virtual host to be used, you need to have a DNS record pointing to your server (hard to to when developing locally), and set it up correctly in your virtual host config.
OR, you can avoid using a virtual host and configure the "MAIN" conf (set the DocumentRoot in the conf file toplevel ). In this case, the apache will answer every request, wherever they are pointing to.